# Get undefined in req.body.id (body-parser and express 4) Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var person = require('./routes/person');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/person', person);

module.exports = app;
```

routes/person.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var router = express.Router();

/* GET  page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('person', {
        message: 'Person works'
    });
});

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    res.send('Thank you!');
    console.log(req.body.firstname);
    console.log(req.body.lastname);
});
```

views/person.pug:

```
    extends layout

block content
    h1 Welcome #{id}
    p= message
    br
    h2= qstr
    br
    form(method='post', action='/person')
        label First name      
        input#firstname(type='text')    
        br   
        label Last name 
        input#lastname(type='text')
        input(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

Questions:

1) Is it necessary in every route to add?:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

2) Why do I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You don't need to use body-parser in every route. Body-parser is a middleware which is used to obtain data from [application/x-www-urlencoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) content type. So if you're sure sure that data you will get in your body is not x-www-urlencoded type, you don't need to use it.

2.Please check if you are passing the data in post request. You can use chrome extension postman to form any kind of query.

Comment: [Image](https://i.gyazo.com/44c9d9a08ec001424e3c40a2fce4cd4f.png)

Solved!, can you explain me why dont works when I put the values in the browser?

Comment: Well, if you declare body-parser in app.js isnt necessary to put anything!

Comment: Well Done mate! The only thing you can do from a browser is to send specific urls and append query parameters to it. But they will from a get request. That's why you need to use an extension.(You can also use a form with a post method)